# In Views, what is the difference between "Show Fields" and "Show Content" under Format?

Tags: 7, views

In the Format section you have the option Show: Fields. That is the one I usually use. However, you also have Show:content. What is Show:content and how is it different? When would I want to use it instead of Show:fields?

Comment: +1 upvote. Also applies to Drupal 8 - please add the '8' tag thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Show: content` will render the content as it is normally displayed if you access it at its URL.  For example, selecting `Show: content` for a view displaying users will display each user's full profile.  Selecting it for a view displaying nodes will render each node in its entirety.

`Show: fields`, by contrast, allows you to select (limit) which fields to display.

Comment: True, but why would one use Show Content instead of Fields? What's the point? Is it simply the case that if I wanted to show all fields instead of selecting the ones I want I would choose this to save time?

Comment: If you want the default node display, you use `Show content`.  You could manually create that using fields, but that would be 1) a waste of time and 2) will add a bunch of Views HTML markup which you don't need (unless you uncheck the boxes under style, which would be a further waste of time).

Answer (score 0):

Show content will bring you the ability to choose a View Mode (say 'top_view_mode'). 
Then, you can create a template like thisone :
nodes--article--top-view-mode.html.twig

From this template use {{ node.field_name.value }}