# Can Display Suite be used for "Show: Fields" as well as "Show: Content" to be able to rewrite field output?

Tags: views, 8, display-suite

I need to be able to adjust field output in view results but also want to make use of [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) for layout.

However, it would appear that Display Suite is only available for "Show: Content" and not "Show: Fields" View Display Format and therefore the facility to rewrite output is not available.

Definition and comparison of "Show: Content" vs "Show: Fields"

[In Views, what is the difference between "Show Fields" and "Show Content" under Format?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55271/in-views-what-is-the-difference-between-show-fields-and-show-content-under)

Comment: Seems like you've almost answered the question yourself, Display Suite is of course only available if you render an entity. However, it's not necessarily one vs the other, you can use both at the same time, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271256/can-you-render-data-from-forced-fields-in-views-while-using-format-show-conten/271299#271299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: no. But there is an alternative solution.

No - (At the time of writing), Display Suite does not *appear* to have functionality  for laying out fields in a view result row for “Show: Fields” format.

For laying out views row results, using display suite is only available for Views outputting the full node (i.e. Show: Content) as a row. The layout is done in the manage display section of the content type, defining a view mode for use in outputting the node in the view.

The solution therefore for laying out fields ( “Show: Fields” format ) and so making available the standard view functionality to modify each field's output behaviour for the view row result would be:

- use the [views_fieldsets](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets) module to group fields in parent `div` containers as required
- use css to layout these parent divs and their children as required. for example, see: [How to place Text and an Image next to each other in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219757/how-to-place-text-and-an-image-next-to-each-other-in-html)
- access each field's settings as usual in the Views Edit Display, to customise the field's output e.g. rewrite it.